# Is there another name for involature?

Tags: keyboard, teaching

This answer...

https://music.stackexchange.com/a/45206/23919

...caught my attention, because while I know about partimenti and solfeggi, I hadn't heard of involature.

I looked for some at IMSLP, but found nothing search on the word *involature*.

Is there another name for this kind of music?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is just a typo for "intavolatura."

The Italian verb *intavolare* means to begin or commence. Musical intavolature were either "preludes" in the sense of the first piece in a collection, or sometimes "music tutors" - e.g. [this on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Intavolatura_di_liuto_et_di_chitarrone_(Piccinini%2C_Alessandro)) for lute (warning, not much use except to show the title page, unless you can read Italian and lute tablature!)

For example a YouTube video claiming to be a performance of an "Involatura per organo e cimbalo" by Zipoli was titled "Intavolatura" in the published first edition. See Page 18 of the PDF (page number 6 of the edition) at https://imslp.org/wiki/Sonate_d%27Intavolatura_per_Organo_e_Cimbalo%2C_Op.1_(Zipoli%2C_Domenico) and the performance at

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It looks like there are many items at IMSLP too.

Comment: It seems 'intavolatura' is another name for 'figuration prelude'

Answer (score 3):

I found a different definition of *intavolatura*. Meaning scoring. In Elizabethan times, of the arrangement of madrigals for keyboard performance - the choral originals being in parts, not in score. Sort of related to partimenti?

Can't find anything relating to 'involature'.

Comment: Where did you find that? Actually, keyboard arrangements of madrigals is something I want. I wish there were the madrigal equivalent of Bach's 371 Harmonized Chorales for keyboard.

Comment: I see that meaning now in Google results. Maybe I can trace that to some madrigal arrangments. According to Richard's answer which I linked intavolatura are connected to partimenti and solfeggi, but just becoming aware of intavolatura.